# Fixing escape sequence \+

Tags: awk

I have a ternary operator in awk with the problem that the escape sequence `\+' treated as plain` +'.  How can I fix it?

```
rl = globrl == 1 ? "?(+)+([" dgt "])" : "^\+?[" dgt "]+$"
```

Comment: Escape the escape?  \\+

Comment: Could you explain the need for escaping the escape?

Comment: Could you explain the need for escaping the escape?  I escape the '+' as it is an awk metacharacter using `\+`.  Why is there a need to escape the escape again in a dynamic regex?  Have not found information about this.

Comment: `+` does not need escaping inside a **string**, where `"\+"` is equivalent to `"+"`. It **does** need to be escaped in a **regular expression**. Backslash is a metacharacter inside strings. To get a literal backslash into a string, you specify `"\\"`.

Comment: `r1` is a **string**. However, its **value** can be used as a regular expression, eg `$0 ~ r1`. To create that value (backslash followed by plus) you declare a string with an escaped backslash followed by a plus.

Comment: I understand now.  One escapes the backslash so the string records `\+`, which is then the required expression in the `regex` for defining a literal `+`.  Thank you.

Comment: contrast with tabs: `"\t"` (string containing tab), `"\\t"` (string containing backslash followed by letter t), `/\t/` (regex matching tab), `/\\t/` (regex matching backslash followed by letter t); `$0 ~ "\\t"` (string containing backslash followed by t used as regex (equivalent to `/\t/`)) and `$0 ~ "\t"` (string used as regex containing literal tab)

Comment: @Avacha : that's why i always advocate using square brackets to "cage" the characters instead of `\\\\\\\\……` nonstop. inside the cage, `[+]` gets you literal `"+"`, `[*]` gets you literal `"*"`, `[?]` gets you literal `"?"`, `[$]` gets you literal `"$"`, outside, they have their special meanings. Just cage them all instead of having to fuss about which flavor of regex which character is special inside char-class, outside char-class, next to this, behind that, all that mess …….

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is described in the following article:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html

Below I give an example that shows the solution to the problem.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {
    a = "^\+?["
    b = "^\\+?["

    print a
    print b
}
'
^+?[
^\+?[
```